# How to disable TRACE method in H2O server

Tags: h2o, http-method

How to disable TRACE method in H2O server?

I start up h2o server via "java -jar h2o.jar" command, however the TRACE http-method is enabled. For security issue, where do I disable TRACE method. 
I check the web engine of H2O is jetty, does h2o can set jetty configuration file on start up command?

Sincerely Yours